# how to implement dragging of graphic elements in echarts graph chart with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

Key Words: vue echarts graph drag

I want to make a graph chart with draggable nodes.

I use graphic to create circles with the dragging function on nodes.

there are two bugs:

1. When I move one node, the other nodes will move too.
2. Although I update the option immediately when the data change, but the chart always change a few seconds later.

You can init a vue-project with vue-cli3 and npm install echarts.

Then you can copy the codes to instead of the App.vue.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="charts" ref="chart" style="height:70vh;"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import echarts from 'echarts'
export default {
  data () {
    return  {
      myChart: null,
      option: {},
      graph: {
        nodes: [
          {
            name: 'Node1',
            x: 300,
            y: 300
          },
          {
            name: 'Node2',
            x: 800,
            y: 300
          },
          {
            name: 'Node3',
            x: 550,
            y: 100
          },
          {
            name: 'Node4',
            x: 550,
            y: 500
          }
        ],
        links: [
          {
            source: 0,
            target: 1,
            symbolSize: [5, 20],
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true
              }
            },
            lineStyle: {
              normal: {
                width: 5,
                curveness: 0.2
              }
            }
          },
          {
            source: 'Node2',
            target: 'Node1',
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true
              }
            },
            lineStyle: {
              normal: { curveness: 0.2 }
            }
          },
          {
            source: 'Node1',
            target: 'Node3'
          },
          {
            source: 'Node2',
            target: 'Node3'
          },
          {
            source: 'Node2',
            target: 'Node4'
          },
          {
            source: 'Node1',
            target: 'Node4'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.initChart()
    this.renderChart()
  },
  methods: {
    initChart () {
      this.myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('charts'));
    },
    renderChart() {
      this.myChart.showLoading();
      this.formatOption();
      this.initDrag();
    },
    formatOption () {
      this.option = {
        title: {
          text: 'Graph 简单示例'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        animationDurationUpdate: 1500,
        animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
        series : [
          {
            type: 'graph',
            layout: 'none',
            symbolSize: 50,
            roam: 'scale',
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true
              }
            },
            edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'],
            edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
            edgeLabel: {
              normal: {
                textStyle: {
                  fontSize: 20
                }
              }
            },
            nodes: this.graph.nodes,
            links: this.graph.links,
            lineStyle: {
              normal: {
                opacity: 0.9,
                width: 2,
                curveness: 0
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      };
      this.myChart.hideLoading();
      this.myChart.setOption(this.option, true);
    },
    initDrag () {
      this.option.graphic = echarts.util.map(this.graph.nodes, (item, dataIndex) => {
        return {
          type: 'circle',
          position: this.myChart.convertToPixel({seriesIndex: 0}, [item.x, item.y]),
          shape: {
            r: 10
          },
          // invisible: true,
          style: {
            fill: 'blue'
          },
          draggable: true,
          ondrag: echarts.util.curry(this.onPointDragging, dataIndex),
          z: 100
        }
      });
      this.myChart.setOption(this.option);
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.updatePosition);
    },
    updatePosition () {
      this.myChart.setOption({
          graphic: echarts.util.map(this.graph.nodes, (item, dataIndex) => {
              return {
                  position: this.myChart.convertToPixel({seriesIndex: 0}, [item.x, item.y])
              };
          })
      });
    },
    onPointDragging (dataIndex, event) {
      let pos = this.myChart.convertFromPixel({seriesIndex: 0}, [event.offsetX, event.offsetY]) // 将graphic的像素坐标转化为坐标系坐标
      this.graph.nodes[dataIndex].x = pos[0] // 将新的坐标系坐标赋值给node
      this.graph.nodes[dataIndex].y = pos[1]
      this.myChart.setOption({
        series: {
          nodes: this.graph.nodes
        }
      })
      this.updatePosition()
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
#charts {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(18,208,253,.5);
}
</style>
```